# scalajs: calling a javascript function with a js.Dynamic.literal works, but not with a js.Object

Tags: scala.js

I am writing a scalajs facade for a function that expects an object parameter.
Simplifying, it looks like this:

notification.js

```
function notification(options) {
    console.log("options", options);
}
```

example.scala:

```
import scala.scalajs.js

class Options(val message: String, val timeout: js.UndefOr[Int] = js.undefined) extends js.Object

@js.native
@js.annotation.JSGlobalScope
object DOMGlobalScope extends js.Object {
  def notification(options: js.Object): Unit = js.native
}

DOMGlobalScope.notification(js.Dynamic.literal(message = "hello", timeout = 100))
//  the browser prints: options {timeout: 100}

DOMGlobalScope.notification(new Options(message = "hello", timeout = 100))
//  the browser prints: options a {timeout: 100}  << what is this a?
```

The library that I am facading, it works if I use `js.Dynamic.literal`, but it doesn't if I use `new Options`.
Is this related to that `a`?

How can I solve this?

And, why can't I use a *case* class Options?

Comment: Try making Options a trait instead of a class, that always works work me. I can't recall any difference between JS classes and traits that would be relevant here, so not sure why class wouldn't work to be honest. If trait doesn't work either... use the browser's dev tools debugger to see what exactly doesn't work. It could be specific to the library you're wrapping.

Comment: well, the web console clearly indicates that 'a' thing.
indeed, the official doc proposes to use a trait, but then you need to implement a function with the name arguments. so, if you want add a new field, you need to add it to two places. i cannot stand boilerplate code.
https://www.scala-js.org/doc/interoperability/types.html